# How can I make a shell to show up in my own distro (linux)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, distributions

I am interested in Linux and been digging it for a while. I just learnt to compile a Linux kernel from source and boot it with Grub which lands you with the shell of the kernel.

Now as soon as the kernel is loaded into memory it searches for the `init` to load it. My agenda is to bring up a shell (which a normal user can use - like `bash`).

So, How can I bring it in?

Do I need to configure init to load the bash shell or is there something I could do?

I am building my own distro and I just need the distro to have a shell (bash) and nothing else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hmm. This should not be complicated to achieve, but it's also very complex :)

You can simply do what Alexander suggested (`init=/bin/bash`), and you'll do fine.

The init process is what the kernel calls, and it kicks off *all* of your userland. Login terminal included. If your init just spawns that bash terminal, you're fine. But if that terminal crashes, or exits, init is supposed to clean up. If some of the processes you launch from terminal die, you need to clean up. If they die, then *their* children need a new parrent process, it'll be your init.

I highly recommend dedicating 10 minutes to read this, it's very friendly overview of what `init` does:

http://tilde.town/~elly/userland.txt

Then you'll get closer to understand what it entails to run your own init.

A relevant part of that link says:

> There is only one thing we
>   need to do: provide an initial binary to launch at any of these paths: /sbin/init, /etc/init, /bin/init, or /bin/sh. This process (init) is run as pid 1.
>
> The init process needs to do two things:
>
> - Never exit (if init exits, the kernel panics)
> - Reap zombie processes

The rest of the text then implements a simple init.

Comment: You should bring the relevant information here as a quote.

Answer (score 4):

"terminal" (a physical computer) and "bash" (a shell) are completely different. I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but you can add `init=/bin/bash` to the kernel command line in order to boot straight into bash.

Comment: Thanks, I have made an edit on that. Is there any other way other than `init=/bin/bash` because I need my distro to take me straight to the shell every time instead of `init=/bin/bash` every time.

Comment: You can configure grub to use `init=/bin/bash` every time the Linux kernel is started, if that is what you want. I would recommend using a proper init system instead, though.

Comment: Is there any way I could configure `init` to start my own programs. Doing so, will I be facing any problems - in chain...

Comment: Yes, if you use systemd, you can add your own program as a pretty small and clear `.service` file in `/usr/lib/systemd/system`, enable it with `systemctl` and it will then be started at boot.

Comment: init=/bin/bash doesn't mean make init call bash, it means use bash instead of init.  And you'll definitely need to have *some* other software installed, or what will your user run, from within bash? They'll only be able to run bash itself!   If you want an ultra minimal distribution, I would suggest you look into what is included by default in the 'busybox' docker container, and in fact you may find it useful to try a busybox container and build your distro in a container first, so you can easily build and test it without rebooting

Answer (score 4):

`bash` isn't a terminal, is a shell.

The `init` process, once the boot process has finished and if the machine is running in a text-only runlevel (so without X Windows), calls eventually `getty` which in turn calls `login`. That's the process responsible for presenting the login prompt and allowing users to log in. This is what happens in all Linux distros.

What you want to do is simply to define `bash` as the default login shell for users (assuming you want a multi-user environment).

Comment: While this is the *typical* setup, I'd word it more carefully, since it's by far not the *only* possible setup. If OP only wants a shell, then a getty and login process might be undesirable.

Comment: Yes, in this case the OP should follow @Alexander's answer.